# Sending multiple embeds in one message

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

How do you send multiple embeds in one message? Sending multiple like this:

```
await message.channel.send({embed: { //Send a new embed
        title: "Embed 1",
        fields: [{
            name: "Description",
            value: "The Description"
        }]
    }},
    embed: { //Send a new embed
        title: "Embed 2",
        fields: [{
            name: "Description",
            value: "The Description"
        }]
    }});
```

Gives an output of:

```
[object Object]
Embed 2
Description: The Description
```

I cant find any documentation on sending multiple embeds, there is some mention of it in the discord.js file, sending a list of embeds. Though I have tried this and it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It certainly is possible by using a Webhook to send your message!

[Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/WebhookMessageOptions) is the documentation for the `WebhookMessageOptions`, as you can see the `embeds` option accepts an array of `MessageEmbed`.

Quick example:

```
message.channel.createWebhook('Webhook Name', message.author.displayAvatarURL)
.then(w => w.send({embeds: [
    new Discord.MessageEmbed().setAuthor('Embed 1'),
    new Discord.MessageEmbed().setAuthor('Embed 2'),
]}));
```

This works for up to 10 embeds.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Richembed, it's easier to editing and the style is better.

You need to add two or how much embeds you want to send, like this:

```
let bot1embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setAuthor("Test Bot")
.setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL)
.setColor("#00ff00")
.addField("Hello!", "Hello World")
.addField("I'm an bot", "I'm a bot");
message.channel.send(bot1embed);

let bot2embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setAuthor("Test Bot")
.setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL)
.setColor("#00ff00")
.addField("Hello!", "Hello World")
.addField("I'm an bot", "I'm a bot");
message.channel.send(bot2embed);
```

This way the bot will send two embeds when someone used the command.

Comment: But don't forget about that everyone can only send 6 messages at time. So, you can send 6 embed messages with your bot.

Comment: Does this allow me to say, `message.channel.send(bot1embed, bot2embed)` or does it have to be in separate messages?

Comment: You need to try that but you can send 6 embed message, only using one command.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, I want to send the embeds in ONE message, not multiple.

Comment: I mean like this you created an command okay? 
?botinfo as example and when this command used the bot will send 2 or maximum 6 embed messages to the channel. I understand, what you want to do but I don't know that you can make it that way (botembed, botembed2) but with my way you can send multiple embeds in the channel.